# Slow switching between Users / TTY using HDMI

Tags: nvidia, display, hdmi, 19.04, gdm

Switching to another already logged in user (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>) takes a long time (approx. 10 - 20 seconds).

First, the screen turns black, after some seconds the cursor appears, and then after some time the desktop appears. Sometimes the icons and text is scrambled which can be fixed by resetting Gnome (running `r` from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).

**How can I eliminate this annoying waiting time ??**

---

I have Nvidia Geforce GTX 1060 TI with current nvidia driver from standard repos.

Same setup using VGA cable works fine, it is the same issue for different monitors (one is Full HD and one is 4K).

I found a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691863/screen-mode-switching-painfully-slow), but it is very old and has a different setup and it has no suitable answers.

---

Installed driver:

```
nvidia-driver-418:
  Installed: 418.56-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 418.56-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 418.56-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/restricted amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Output of `sudo lshw -C display`:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:144 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

This is the output from `journalctl -xe` when switching: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/9vYPKjG6DJ/

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` doesn't print anything when switching.

I did not change anything from default settings regarding graphics.

Comment: Please add output of the command `sudo lshw -C display` to Your question. We need to know what kind of nvidia driver is in use.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I updated the question with that information.

Comment: Is there anything in the logs right after the switching in `journalctl -xe` or `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` ?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz added output of `journalctl -xe`.

Comment: This issue is fixed for me  in Ubuntu 19.10. +happy+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is totally fixed for me after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10.
Not sure, but it might have been related to this issue:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1798790
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/issues/483

Answer (score 0):

From Arch Linux: [Slow loading of system icons/slow GDM login](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Troubleshooting)

> ```
> # gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache
> ```
>
> Running the aforementioned command may also fix repeated occurrences
> of the "Oh no! Something has gone wrong!" error screen and/or very
> slow loading and login with GDM as described in the following [forum
> thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1414157).

The above is a tiny fraction of the Arch Linux link and other useful tips / things to try can be found there.

Comment: I get `gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: command not found`. [Ubuntu mapage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man1/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders.1.html) says it is provided by `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin`, but that is installed (`libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin is already the newest version (2.38.1+dfsg-1).`).

Comment: A reinstall of `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-*` and a `dpkg-reconfigure` for these packages didn't help.

Comment: Actually might have to reinstall extension: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154929/ubuntu-19-04-stops-working

Comment: That did not help