# 4 seconds delay when switching to another TTY

Tags: gdm, tty, 20.04, xserver

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F?</kbd> to switch to another TTY (both graphical or not) I get a 3-4 seconds delay where I still see the "old" TTY before the screen switches (which is then almost instant).

In `syslog`, I can see that the seconds are lost right before this message:

```
Apr 26 09:58:32 pc-name gdm3: GLib: Source ID 141 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

More syslog:

```
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (**) Option "fd" "45"
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (**) Option "fd" "26"
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (**) Option "fd" "73"
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (II) event4  - Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000: device removed
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (**) Option "fd" "82"
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (**) Option "fd" "27"
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (II) event3  - Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: device removed
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (**) Option "fd" "82"
Apr 26 09:58:29 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (II) event5  - Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000: device removed
Apr 26 09:58:32 pc-name gdm3: GLib: Source ID 141 was not found when attempting to remove it
Apr 26 09:58:32 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Apr 26 09:58:32 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
Apr 26 09:58:32 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Apr 26 09:58:32 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Apr 26 09:58:32 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Apr 26 09:58:32 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2489]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Apr 26 09:58:32 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6994]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:69
Apr 26 09:58:32 pc-name /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6994]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
```

- Happens only after upgrade to 20.04.
- Happens with both Displayport and HDMI
- Interestingly the delay does not happen when the screen is locked, then also that line does not appear in syslog.

I had a [similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170532/slow-switching-between-users-tty-using-hdmi) before, but this was a delay when creating the new X session, while the new delay happens when shutting down the current X session.

How to find out (and eliminate) what is blocking the x-session shutdown ?

Comment: For me using Kubuntu 20.04 it takes forever and requires pressing twice (i.e. I press Ctrl+Alt+F2, ubuntu fakes a tty change but after 4 seconds of blackness goes back to the original tty, pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 again finally gives me the TTY after an other 3-4 seconds). Moreover when having more than one tty active CPU spikes at 100%. To me it seems it is getting worse after each release (the CPU issue was present in 18.04 but only for multiple graphical sessions)