# Prevent Ubuntu (GDM?) from locking when switching to another TTY

Tags: gnome, login, lock-screen, gdm, tty

In TTY3 I use a simple window manager as my main working area, but sometimes I need to test stuff in a full Gnome environment, so I use it on TTY1, just as the default on a clean Ubuntu install.

But each time I switch from TTY1 to TTY3 and then back again, I have to deal with the GDM lock screen. Note this is not affected by elapsed time.

It is very frustrating because it takes several seconds for the lock screen to show up in the first place ([related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231274/4-seconds-delay-when-switching-to-another-tty)), and then after entering password there is still another couple of seconds delay until I get an usable Gnome session.

How to disable lock screen when switching away from the TTY where Gnome is running?

Comment: Questions:Is it your intent to keep lock screen during normal operations? If not does this also happen when you completly disable the usage of lock screen? and if that is the case would that suffice as an answer?

Comment: [On tty2 you have Gnome (unlocked)](https://askubuntu.com/a/965201/349837)..

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, I would be happy disabling lock screen.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I can't reproduce this exactly, but you can unlock your session with

`loginctl unlock-session`

so you could do this, before switching TTYs, in the current session

`sleep 5 && loginctl unlock-session`

Comment: Didn't work to me :(